# How to Highlight Multiple Polygons at Once Based on Properties Value

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to figure out how to highlight multiple polygons/features based on the `feature.properties.NAME` value. My polygons are a bit broken up so they are separate features and using an `onEachFeature` function will only highlight the specific shape mouseover as opposed to all of them with the same name.

```
// current function being used to highlight
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.on('mouseover', () => {
      layer.setStyle({
        weight: 4,
        opacity: 0.7
      });
    }),
    layer.on('mouseout', () => {
      layer.setStyle({
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 0.85
      });
    })
}
```

for example here is a jsfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/anwgture/10/](https://jsfiddle.net/anwgture/10/). When mousing over a "SHAPE-A" polygon it should highlight the 3 (top, top left, bottom right) and mousing over "SHAPE-B" should highlight the 2 (right, bottom left).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using QGIS's `collect geometries` joining them on the `NAME` to change the polygons into mulipolygons which resolved the issue.